# Failed to instantiate module demoApp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'demoApp' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, ngroute

I am trying to build a simple SPA using angular and ngRoute/ngView. I simply cannot make it work.

I get the error: angular.js:68
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module demoApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'demoApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I have looked at various code examples on the web as well as youtube tutorials and compared my code to theirs, but I simply cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. To me, they look identical.

I apologize in advance, this seems to be a question that has been asked a lot in the past, but previous answers have not been to any help for me.

This is my HTML-file, it is called "test.html".

```
<html ng-app="demoApp">
  <head>
        <title>My Angular App</title>

  </head>

  <body>
      <h2>DemoApp Demo</h2>
        <div>
            <a href="#/partial1.html">Partial 1</a>
            <a href="#/partial2.html">Partial 2</a>
            <div ng-view></div>     
        </div>
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src = "demoApp.js" />
  </body>
</html>
```

This is "demoApp.js", it is in the same directory as test.html

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);

demoApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        .when('/partial1',
        {
            controller: 'SimpleController',
            templateUrl: 'Partials/partial1.html'
        }).when('/partial2',
        {
            controller: 'SimpleController',
            templateUrl: 'Partials/partial2.html'
        }).otherwise({redirectTo: '/partial1'});
}]);


demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function($scope){
    $scope.customers = [
        {name:'Victor', city:'Norrköping'}, 
        {name:'Mikael', city:'Göteborg'}, 
        {name:'Jocke',  city:'Göteborg'}, 
        {name:'Skåne',  city:'Ystad'}
    ];

    $scope.addCustomer = function(){
        $scope.customers.push(
        {
            name: $scope.newCustomer.name, 
            city: $scope.newCustomer.city
        });
    }
});
```

I did not include Partial1 and Partial2 as they seem irrelevant to the problem as they are only simple HTML files with no scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in the line

```
<script src="..." />
```

You cannot have self closing `script` tags, so it should be

```
<script src="..." > </script>
```

Plunker demonstrating answer: http://plnkr.co/edit/Mz1GRSFRxaUN9q6gUONl

Comment: Figured it would be something silly like that. Had no idea you could not end script tags with '/'. Thanks a lot, you cured my headache.

Comment: You're welcome haha, also already I hit quite the head with something silly. Welcome to AngularJS World !